# How can I make emacs open a particular file always in outline mode?

Tags: emacs

I want to create a file called `~/todo` and make Emacs always open that file in outline mode. How can I do that?

Is there an extension I can add to the filename that will trigger outline mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the following on the first line of the file:

```
; -*- mode: outline -*-
```

You can use `#` instead of `;` if it fits your style better.

Comment: You can also use "nothing at all" or anything else for that matter instead of `;`.